# Unable to get items from List of Class in JSON response

Tags: jquery, json

In .Net I am using an AJAX call that returns me a list of a class, in this list one of the properties is a list of Email \ Contact information.

When I get the JSON data back from the Web Method, I am iterating through it and getting the information out as I need until I come to iterate through the list of Email \ Contact Information.

Using this code

```
if (data.d[0].Emails.length > 0) {
       $.each(data.d[0].Emails, function () {
           var something = "";
       });
    }
```

the object data.d[0].Emails has a length that is greater than 0, and if I look at this using my debugger I can see all the values that I am expecting.

However, the issue that I am having is when I get into the $.each data.d[0].Emails becomes undefined and all the information that I am after is lost.

When debugging in Visual Studio the message I get is 'data' is underfined

I would be grateful to understand how and where I am going wrong and to be able to get the information out.

this is the entire ajax method

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Admin.aspx/GetCmcContactInformation",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            var d = data.d;
            console.log(d);
            $("#MainContent_txtAddressLine1").val(data.d[0].AddressLine1);
            $("#MainContent_txtAddressLine2").val(data.d[0].AddressLine2);
            $("#MainContent_txtCity").val(data.d[0].City);
            $("#MainContent_txtPostcode").val(data.d[0].PostCode);
            $("#MainContent_txtCmcComments").val(data.d[0].Notes);

            if (data.d[0].Emails.length > 0) {

                if (data.d[0].Emails.length > 0) {
                    $.each(data.d[0].Emails, function (index, email) {
                        var something = "";
                    });
                }
            }

            $("#saveModal").modal("hide");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("error :" + data);
            console.log(data);
            $("#saveModal").modal("hide");
            $("#newUser").hide("slow");

        }
    });
```

thanks

Simon

Comment: can u post the json in data.d[0].Emails?

Comment: @Mir The information I get back contains sensitive customer information, but its not the JSON that's the issue. the issue is the value of data becomes undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may just be your sample code, but it appears that you are using the wrong method signature for your callback. If you refer to the documentation for [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), you need to define two arguments for the callback. In the sample code below each item would be available in the `email` argument:

```
if (data.d[0].Emails.length > 0) {
   $.each(data.d[0].Emails, function (index, email) {
       var something = "";
   });
}
```